# Refresh Detail Data Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a master and detail page. For Master table i have 4 text box displayed in detail layout and for detail table i have data grid. There is trigger on master table which insert some records in detail table. i want to refresh the detail data grid from database. How i can refresh detail data grid with database changes. [Here is image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjZlF.jpg) Data is inserted in upper form and there is trigger on upper form which insert data in detail table. I want to load data inserted by triggers in below grid. I m using Entity Framework and using context.SaveChanges(); to save data in database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Master details information displayed on same page; If there is your case, it is easy. when you are going to insert something in your master table, You can get updated records from detail tables based on PK. One downsize of this approach is, you need to be 100% sure how much trigger will take time.(I am not sure ADO.Net return status of ExecuteNonquery after insert row in specific table or completion of triggers). 
In your case when you saveChanges(), make a request to get details against user. Hopefully it is the easiest way to achieve goal.

But if Master and details pages are separate, or information can be changed from other mean. Then you can use SqlDependency. Please Note that SqlDependency only works with SQL server. It monitor DB changes in specific table, and notify ADO.Net. You can handle SqlDependency.OnChange.